# Code execution time: how to properly DRY several timeit executions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dry, timeit

Let's assume we want to use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) for some performance testing with different inputs.

The obvious, non-[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) way would be something like this:

```
import timeit

# define functions to test
def some_list_operation_A(lst):
    ...

def some_list_operation_B(lst):
    ...

# create different lists (different input) to test the functions with
...
inputs = [lsta, lstb, lstc, ...]

# measure performance with first function
num = 10
t_lsta = timeit.timeit("some_list_operation_A(lsta)",
                        setup="from __main__ import some_list_operation_A, lsta",
                        number=num)
t_lstb = timeit.timeit("some_list_operation_A(lstb)",
                        setup="from __main__ import some_list_operation_A, lstb",
                        number=num)
t_lstc = timeit.timeit("some_list_operation_A(lstc)",
                        setup="from __main__ import some_list_operation_A, lstc",
                        number=num)
...

# print results & do some comparison stuff
for res in [t_lsta, t_lstb, t_lstc, ...]:
    print("{:.4f}s".format(res))
    ...

# do this ALL OVER AGAIN for 'some_list_operation_B'
...

# print new results

# do this ALL OVER AGAIN for 'some_list_operation_C'
# ...I guess you'll got the point
...
```

I think it should be very clear that this would be a really ugly way to measure the performance of different functions for different input.

What I currently do is something like this:

```
...
inputs = dict()
inputs["lsta"] = lsta
inputs["lstb"] = lstb
inputs["lstc"] = lstc

for f in ["some_list_operation_A", "some_list_operation_B", ...]:
    r = dict()  # results
    for key, val in inputs.iteritems():
        r[key] = timeit.timeit("{}(inputs[{}])".format(f, key),
                                setup="from __main__ import {}, inputs".format(f),
                                number=num

    # evaluate results 'r' for function 'f' here
    # (includes a comparison of the results -
    #  that's why I save them in 'r')
    ...

    # loop moves on to next function 'f'
```

Basically, I am using `.format` here to insert the function name and insert the right data `inputs[key]`. After `.format` fills all `{}`, the result is one correct `stmt` string of `timeit`.

While this is a lot shorter than the obvious non-DRY solution, it is also less readable and more like hack, isn't it?

What would be an appropriate DRY solution for such problems?

I also thought of simply timing the functions with **decorators** (this would be neat?!) - but I did not succeed: the decorator should not only print the result. In my `# evaluate results 'r'`-step I am not only printing the results, but I am also comparing them: like computing relative differences and stuff. Thus, I would need the decorator to return something in order to compare the results for each run...

Can someone hint me in the right direction for a clean, pythonic solution? I would like to have more beautiful/ideomatic code...and especially: **shorter** code!

Comment: I honestly don't know that you can do any better than what you have now. The flexibility given by `timeit`'s use of a string input rather than just a function also means that it's going to look a little clunkier when you try to put a bunch of them together programmatically like this.

Comment: I thought a `decorator` should be neat, but as I mentioned I just get it to print the result for each function call...while I want it to store the results to some dict, list or whatever, in order to do comparison stuff in addition to the plain printing of the results.

Comment: If you really like the idea of a decorator, storing the results of a function call is essentially what [memoization](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578231-probably-the-fastest-memoization-decorator-in-the-/) is for, and is a classic example of how decorators can be useful.

Comment: This looks interesting, thank you for the input!